# Angular js .then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this service that loads data..

```
 angular.module('App').service('daysService', ['$http','$q',function($http,$q) {

    var days = [];

      return {
                 loadDay: function() {
                    $http({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: '/app/days/list/',
                  }).success(function(data) {              
                    days.push(data);
                    return days;  
                  }).error(function (data) {
                      console.log('Error checking server.');
                  });
                }
            };

      }]);
```

than in the controller i call the service

```
daysService.loadDay.then(function(data) {
   alert(data)
});
```

But i'm getting this error `TypeError: daysService.loadDay.then is not a function`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Change `service` to `factory`

Comment: did you try using `loadDay()` instead of `loadDay`? Considering its a function...

Comment: @nem has got the answer, but the way you are using the `service` is actually how you use a `factory`, if you were using the `service` properly then you would have declared `loadDay` like this: `this.loadDay = function () {}` with out returning anything

Comment: with loadDay() now i have this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @Fr4ncx make my change now.. the error is telling you that loadDay is undefined... which it is in your scenario

Comment: You are also not returning anything from the `loadDay` function

Comment: @sma i return the days..

Comment: you have to return the `$http` also

Comment: add getDays fucntion to return Object of service and call it by controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your `loadDay` function.  Try this:

```
return {
    loadDay: function() {
        return $http({   // <-- return the promise
            method: 'get',
            url: '/app/days/list/',
        }).success(function(data) {              
            days.push(data);
            return days;  
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error checking server.');
        });
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
daysService.loadDay.then(function(data) {
   alert(data)
});
```

On the first line you are not calling `loadDay` like a function you are accessing it as a property. so you need to change it to this:

```
 daysService.loadDay().then(function(data) {
   alert(data)
});
```

Note the parenthesis on `loadDay`.

Secondly, you are using a service like a factory. So you have two options:

```
angular.module('App').service('daysService', ['$http','$q',function($http,$q) {   
    var days = [];

    this.loadDay = function() {
                    $http({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: '/app/days/list/',
                  }).success(function(data) {              
                    days.push(data);
                    return days;  
                  }).error(function (data) {
                      console.log('Error checking server.');
                  });
                };
      }]);
```

OR

```
angular.module('App').factory('daysService', ['$http','$q',function($http,$q) {
  var days = [];

  return {
             loadDay: function() {
                $http({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/app/days/list/',
              }).success(function(data) {              
                days.push(data);
                return days;  
              }).error(function (data) {
                  console.log('Error checking server.');
              });
            }
        };

  }]);
```

Finally, you aren't returning the promise from the function:

```
function() {
    return $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/app/days/list/',
    }).success(function(data) {
        days.push(data);
        return days;
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error checking server.');
    });
};
```

And if I were doing this, I would do:

```
angular.module('App').factory('daysService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var days = [];

    this.loadDay = function() {
        return $http.get('/app/days/list/').then(
            function(data) {
              days.push(data);
              return days;
            },
            function(data) {
              console.log('Error checking server.');
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your factory should return a promise instead of `days` if you want to use `.then()`. I believe you can do something like `return $q.when(days)` instead of `return days` and that should work.

Also just to note, `.success()` and `.failure()` callbacks are deprecated as of Angular 1.4. Not sure which version you're using, but `$http` now uses `.then` following this pattern:

```
$http({stuff}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //success
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // error
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.module('App').service('daysService', ['$http','$q',function($http,$q) {

var days = [];

  return {
             loadDay: function() {
                $http({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/app/days/list/',
              }).success(function(data) {              
                days.push(data);
                //return days;  
              }).error(function (data) {
                  console.log('Error checking server.');
              });
            },getDays: function(){ return days; }

        };

  }]);
```

---

```
daysService.loadDay(); $window.alert(daysService.getDays());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a promise only then will you be able to use it with `.then()`. Check this document on how to create a promise. It is simple. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

You code is right now incapable of using `.then()` and the object/object property is not present so the error `TypeError: daysService.loadDay.then is not a function`. Else write a code that does not require you to use `.then()` but can work as normally triggered functions. That will work too.

```
/* In your service  */
angular.module('App').factory('daysService', ['$http',function($http) {

    var days = [];

      return {
                 loadDay: function() {
                    $http({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: '/app/days/list/',
                  }).success(function(data) {              
                    days.push(data);
                    return days;  
                  }).error(function (data) {
                      console.log('Error checking server.');
                      return;
                  });
                }
            };

      }]);

/* In your controller trigger the eventorclick */
$scope.trigger = function(){
$scope.modelname = daysService.loadDay(); /* returns days else undefined or null */
alert($scope.modelname); /* handle your issues if you have array of objects */
}
```